# Counting of conditional frequency in R

Tags: r

I have a table with only one column and more than 200 rows. It includes three values, 0, 1 and 3. I´m interested in only these incidents, where an 1 follwos a 0. Can R count all X=1 if X-1 = =, given that X is the value of any row.

It would be great, if someone could help !
Best, Anna

Comment: could you please clarify what the desirable output is and provide sample data (```dput()```)?

Comment: use `dplyr::lead()`  like `df %>% summarise(count = sum(incident == 1 & lead(incident) == 0, na.rm = T))`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```r
# Create some sample data
set.seed(2020)
df <- data.frame(incident = sample(c(0, 1, 3), 10, replace = TRUE))
#   incident
#1         3
#2         1
#3         0
#4         0
#5         1
#6         1
#7         0
#8         0
#9         1
#10        1

sum(c(df$incident[-1] == 1, FALSE) * (df$incident == 0))
# Or: with(df, sum(c(incident[-1] == 1, FALSE) * (incident == 0)))
#[1] 2
```

Here, `c(incident[-1] == 1, FALSE) * (incident == 0)` is the logical AND of x[i-1] = 0 and x[i] = 1. `sum` then sums the number of occurrences (in this case there are 2: one in rows 4/5 and one in rows 8/9).

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

(df <- tibble(value = sample(c(0, 1, 3),size = 200, replace = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 200 x 1
#>    value
#>    <dbl>
#>  1     3
#>  2     3
#>  3     3
#>  4     1
#>  5     3
#>  6     1
#>  7     1
#>  8     1
#>  9     3
#> 10     0
#> # … with 190 more rows

count <- 0

#use map instead of walk to view the process row by row
walk(2:nrow(df), ~ {
  if (df$value[[.x - 1]] == 0 && df$value[[.x]] == 1) count <<- count + 1
})

count
#> [1] 26

#some rows where the pattern is happening
df[86:87, ]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   value
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     0
#> 2     1
df[93:94, ]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   value
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     0
#> 2     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Using dplyr:

```r
transmute(df, dif = c(NA, diff(value))) %>%
  count(dif) %>%
  filter(dif == 1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>     dif     n
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1    26
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>